# WPF: Performance Impact of Databinding Tracing

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, data-binding, trace

We use DataBinding in our WPF application. For troubleshooting and detection of binding errors we use *diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel* with Tracing Level High.
My question is:
Does this option affect the performance in the productive version? Should tracing only be used temporarily in the event of an error and then removed again? Will it be automatically removed while compiling?

I attached some demo wpf xaml code.

```xml
<UserControl
        [....]
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase">

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=BooleanValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />

</UserControl>
```

Comment: This is easy to test, but I'd definitely get rid of it. It's not omitted in a release build. You can dispense with the `diag:` namespacing, by the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Where did you get this Kind of Information? I cant find any Kind of ressource.

Comment: I built a release build with a trace in it.